# QWidget loses its parent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qdialog

In my application I have a `QDialog` which itself contains a complex, `QWidget`-derived GUI element. The `QDialog` is modal and opened with `exec()` and the embedded GUI element handles all user interactions.

So only this child `QWidget` knows when the `QDialog` can be closed, which is done this way:

```
QDialog* parent=qobject_cast<QDialog*>(parentWidget());
if (parent) parent->close();
```

This is necessary because the `QDialog` has to be closed and not only the `QWidget`.

Now a user reported a situation where `QDialog::exec()` has returned but where the dialog (or only the GUI element?) was still visible. From the log files I can see `QDialog::exec()` really has returned and the code right after this call was executed.

So my current assumption: the GUI element has lost its parent so that the `close()` call shown above was not called because "parent" was null.

Any idea how this can happen? Is there a regular way where the parent of a `QWidget` can disappear?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't just connect a signal of your child to the `accept()` or `reject()` slot of the dialog?

Comment: @thuga I can not reproduce this problem here, so this comment is completely useless

Comment: Well then write that in the question.

Comment: @thuga it is already mentioned with the sentence "Now a user reported a situation..."

Comment: So anything reported by users means automatically that it cannot be reproduced? Anyway, `QDialog::exec` returns only when the dialog is hidden (or closed). Can you tell us if it is possible that the dialog was created twice?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, using `QDialog::exec` to reenter the event loop will cause trouble, because suddenly all the code that runs in the main thread must be reentrant. Most likely you're facing fallout from that. Don't reenter the event loop, and you'll be fine or the problem will become reproducible.

If you need to react to the dialog being accepted or rejected, connect code to the relevant slots. I.e. change this:

```
void do() {
  MyDialog dialog{this};
  auto rc = dialog.exec();
  qDebug() << "dialog returned" << rc;
}
```

to that:

```
class Foo : public QWidget {
  MyDialog dialog{this};
  ...
  Foo() {
    connect(&dialog, &QDialog::done, this, &Foo::dialogDone);
  }
  void do() {
    dialog.show();
  }
  void dialogDone(int rc) {
    qDebug() << "dialog returned" << rc;
  }
};
```

or, if you want to lazily initialize the dialog:

```
class Foo : public QWidget {
  MyDialog * m_dialog = nullptr;
  MyDialog * dialog() {
    if (! m_dialog) {
      m_dialog = new MyDialog{this};
      connect(m_dialog, &QDialog::done, this, &Foo::dialogDone);
    }
    return m_dialog;
  }
  ...
  void do() {
    dialog()->show();
  }
  void dialogDone(int rc) {
    qDebug() << "dialog returned" << rc;
  }
};
```

It is a horrible antipattern for the child widget to attempt to meddle with the parent. **The knowledge that the widget has a parent should not leak into the widget, it should be localized to the parent.** Thus, the child widget should emit a signal that indicates that e.g. the data was accepted. When you create the dialog, connect this signal to the dialog's `accept()` or `close()` slots:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void isDone();
  ...
};

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
  QGridLayout layout{this};
  MyWidget widget;
public:
  MyDialog() {
    layout.addWidget(&widget, 0, 0);
    connect(&widget, &MyWidget::isDone, this, &QDialog::accepted);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't mentioned in the docs, that nested event loops such as `QDialog::exec` should be avoided if possible. It is mentioned in some blogs, but I think it should be more obvious.